# display input field with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to display all values from inputs into a div. I would like my final output to look like this:

`startmsg middlemsg *NAME-FROM-SELECT-MENU* endmsg *TEXT-FROM-INPUT-FIELD*`

Here is my code:

```
<select id="names">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Alex">Alex</option>
  <option value="Jeff">Jeff</option>
  <option value="Amy">Amy</option>
  <option value="Kate">Kate</option>
</select>
<input id="message" type="text" />
<input id="clear" type="submit" value="Clear" />
<div id="display"></div>


$('#names')('#message').keyup(function () {
  $('#display').append('starmsg').append('middlemsg').text($(this).val().append('endmsg'));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reckon your code isn't too far away.  You want the multiple selector, and probably also the `change` event rather than `keyup`. You also need to call `append` on jQuery objects, rather than strings:

```
$('#names, #message').change(function () {
    $('#display')
        .text('startmsg ')
        .append(' middlemsg ')
        .append($('#names').val())
        .append(' endmsg ')
        .append($('#message').val());
});
```

Comment: thanks thats exactly what i was trying to accomplish. only thing is that `startmsg` and `middlemsg` don't appear http://jsfiddle.net/yvTNc/5/

Comment: @sarsar See update. `text` overwrites existing content; `append` adds to it.

Comment: thank you. also how can i clear #display, #message, and #names all at the same time by the click on a button?

Comment: `$('#display, #message, #names').empty()`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, i would suggest .each on the the input and select tags

See the following link for more info, it does exactly the thing you want.

[jQuery .each](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are after http://jsfiddle.net/DUytH/

```
function update(){
  $('#display')
        .text('start ' +
              $('#message').val() +
              ' end ' +
              $('#names').val());  
}
$('#message').keyup(update);
$('#names').change(update);
```